# How to attribute multiple images to the same observation in a neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, pytorch

I have a data set of houses with each house containing 5 - 8 images each.  Each image is a different aspect of the home (roof, right side, left side, etc).  The target variable is binary per house.  How would I feed in each record's multiple images in a way that the neural net knows which record each image is attributed to?

Any ideas in Keras or pytorch is appreciated.

Now that I’m back at my work desk, maybe this record would help. The following is one actual record from the tabular dataset.

```
ID: 5000686
Age of Home: 34
Zip Code: 49508
Home Value: 200000
Number of families living in home: 1
Target: 1
```

So for reach photo, the title is the ‘id-photo number.’ I have a csv with three columns that shows the location on my hard drive, full photo ID, and meta label. I have 8 to 28 photos per record.

```
5000686-136279724.jpg / meta-label = dwelling
5000686-136279725.jpg / meta-label = dwelling
5000686-136279726.jpg / meta-label = roof
5000686-136279727.jpg / meta-label = roof
5000686-136279728.jpg / meta-label = roof
5000686-136279729.jpg / meta-label = Other
```

Comment: What's your goal ? what do you want to the network to achieve ?

Comment: Good question @ESZ. I want the network to predict the binary target for each record using all the images associated with hat record.